# How does a direct mapped cache with 16 one-word blocks vary from one with 8 two-word blocks

Tags: caching

I am looking to determine Binary address, tag, index, and Hit or miss of a cache with 16 one-word blocks and one which uses 8 2-word blocks all assumed empty at the begginning

Say I have the referenced instructions 4, 4, 32, 31, 5, 32

For the first cache (16 one word blocks) you must first convert 4 to binary then that binary value is split to get tag then if you find that index again it will be mark as a hit

That being said, I believe the table below to be correct using this method.

```
Ref | Binary |  Tag  | Index | Hit or Miss
 4   00000100   0000   0100      miss
 4   00000100   0000   0100      hit
32   00100000   0010   0000      miss
31   00011111   0001   1111      miss
 5   00000101   0000   0101      miss
32   00100000   0010   0000      hit
```

I wish to do the same for the the second cache(8 two-word blocks) however I am unsure how to continue.

I figure the binary is the same for the numbers however I am confused on how to determine tag and index from it and whether there was a hit or a miss on the same referenced instructions as the first cache.

How would one determine the tag, index, and whether or not it was a hit or miss in this cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It varies in that you have half as many cache lines to work with, giving 4 bits of tag, 3 bits of index and 1 bit of displacement within the cache line (indicating which word of a two-word block is addressed).  For the example given, the wider fetches will garner one additional hit since accessing 4 fetches 5 as well.

```
Ref | Binary |  Tag  | Index | Disp |  Hit or Miss
 4   00000100   0000   010     0       miss
 4   00000100   0000   010     0       hit
32   00100000   0010   000     0       miss
31   00011111   0001   111     1       miss
 5   00000101   0000   010     1      *hit
32   00100000   0010   000     0       hit
```

Comment: Okay so that is why there is a hit on the reference to 5, so going with that example if you had a reference to 33 next the tag would be 0010 with and index 000 with a displacement of 1 indicating a hit because the indexes matched?

Comment: *Index and tag* both matched for 5, and the same would apply if 33 were the next read which would be a hit.  However, reading 17 between 32 and 33 would result in two *conflict misses*: tag 0001 would replace tag 0010 at index 000 (evicting 32 and 33 from cache in favor of 16 and 17), only to turn around and reverse the process when 33 is needed.

Comment: Whoops you are correct both index and tag must match but I understand now thank you for clarifying this for me